# Does QXmlSchemaValidator (Qt 4.8) support the XML schema (XSD) attribute "substitutionGroup"

Tags: xml, qt, xsd

QXmlSchemaValidator does not validate my XML when it contains substitutionGroups. Online tools (http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/, http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html) validate the XML, the XSD, and the XML against the XSD.

Error:

```
Error XSDError in file: (XML), at line 44, column 14: Element image_id is not defined in this scope.
```

Relevant code, XSD:

```
  <xs:element name="image_ids" abstract="true"/>
  <xs:element name="image_id" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" substitutionGroup="image_ids"/>
  <xs:element name="image_queue_id" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" substitutionGroup="image_ids"/>

  <xs:element name="image_slot">  
    <xs:complexType>      
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element ref="image_ids" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element ref="caption" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:all>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="position"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Relevant code, XML:

```
  <image_slot x="7" y="110" width="55">
    <image_id>0</image_id> <-- error
    <caption>some caption</caption>
  </image_slot>
```

QXmlSchemaValidator validates the XSD, but not the XML against the XSD. Getting rid of substitutionGroup is enough to validate the XML, but this also means that I lose functionality - incorrect XML files will now be validated. Thus my question is - does Qt actually support XML substitutionGroups, and there is something else I'm doing wrong (that other tools did not notice)?

Or is it a bug in QXmlSchemaValidator, in which case I should just abandon the idea and find another solution?

**Edit: had to wait a day to be able to post my own answer. I have to wait one more day before I can accept it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the elements of a substitution group must be of the same type. This was the case in my XSD, but the type was defined in each element of the group and not at the abstract element level. The following code solved the issue:

XDS code:

```
  <xs:element name="image_ids" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" abstract="true"/>
  <xs:element name="image_id" substitutionGroup="image_ids"/>
  <xs:element name="image_queue_id" substitutionGroup="image_ids"/>

  <xs:element name="image_slot">  
    <xs:complexType>      
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element ref="image_ids" maxOccurs="1"/>
          <xs:element ref="caption" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:all>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="position"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

XML code:

```
  <image_slot x="7" y="110" width="55">
    <image_id>0</image_id>
    <caption>some caption</caption>
  </image_slot>
```

I am unsure why QXmlSchemaValidator validated the schema only to refuse to validate the XML afterwards; hopefully this will help others facing the same issue.